# AutoCompleteTextView sets Object To String

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I'm currently working with an `AutoCompleteTextView`. In the dropdown are several entries. But now I've got a problem. If one of this entries gets clicked, it sets the Object to String of the clicked element into the ACTV. But I don't know why. I have tried to set an `OnItemClickListener`. With or without it, the Object to String gets set. The `getItem` method of the ArrayAdapter gets called, before it sets the string into the ACTV.

What could be the problem? I don't think that any code is needed, because it's just a simple ACTV and ArrayAdapter.

ArrayAdapter:

```
private int LIMIT = 4;

private BasicDataObject[] basicDataObjects = new BasicDataObject[0];
private int resourceCourse, resourceVideo;

public SearchAutoCompleteArrayAdapter(Context context, int resourceCourse, int resourceVideo) {
    super(context, resourceCourse);
    this.resourceCourse = resourceCourse;
    this.resourceVideo = resourceVideo;
}


public void insertAll(BasicDataObject[] basicDataObjects) {
    this.basicDataObjects = basicDataObjects;
    this.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < basicDataObjects.length; i++) {
        this.insert(basicDataObjects[i], i);
    }
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (basicDataObjects[position] instanceof Course) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceCourse, parent, false);
        } else {
            CourseEntry courseEntry = (CourseEntry) basicDataObjects[position];
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceVideo, parent, false);
            ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_playlist);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(courseEntry.getImage(getContext()));
            TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_search_element_text);
            textView.setText(courseEntry.getCourseName());
        }

    }
    convertView.setTag(basicDataObjects[position]);
    return convertView;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return minimumSize();
}

private int minimumSize() {
    return Math.min(basicDataObjects.length, LIMIT);
}

@Override
public BasicDataObject getItem(int position) {
    if (basicDataObjects.length == 0) return null;
    return basicDataObjects[position];
}
```

Implementation:

```
 this.searchAutoCompleteArrayAdapter = new SearchAutoCompleteArrayAdapter(this.getContext(), R.layout.auto_complete_layout_search_course,
            R.layout.auto_complete_layout_search_video);
    this.setAdapter(searchAutoCompleteArrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem. Its works as it supposed to be. You need to **override toString()** method in your object.

Every object has **toString()** method and ArrayAdapter using to show data which makes ArrayAdapter is generic, in other words, independent from custom classes.

**UPDATE**

You need to override also **getDropDownView()** in your adapter. That one is for the selected view in ACTV. By the way you have logic problem in your **getView()**. It always inflates same view. It is not the proper implementation of **ViewHolder pattern**.

Another would be to override **getItemViewType()** and use its returning value in **getView()** for identify types of different rows.

```
    @Override public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        ... // Your logic comes here

        return convertView;
   }
```

Comment: I have used the ACTV before and I'm pretty sure, that it hasn't setted the to String into the ACTV.

Comment: You might used custom implemented ArrayAdapter

Comment: Yes, I have a custom ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Also the codes how you set adapter. (The class that you used your adapter in it)

Answer (score 0):

THe issue is here :

```
 if (basicDataObjects[position] instanceof Course) {
    convertView = inflater.inflate(resourceCourse, parent, false);
  }
```

if it is instanceof Course you are not setting anything.

Also override this method:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     //add the same logic that you have in getView
    }
```

This tells the adapter which view to show while DropDown is Open.

Comment: Why? I also want the ImageView and other elements, not just the TV.